# How do I increment the pointer to a structure which has variable length array?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, increment

I have problem in accessing the pointer to a structure (array passed to function) that has a variable size array.

```
        char name[20];
        char value[20];
   }param_t;
   typedef struct object {
        char name[20];
        int no_of_params;
        param_t params[];
   };

int main()
{
    int no_of_objs = 3, no_of_params = 5;
    object_t *objs = malloc(no_of_objs * (sizeof(object_t) + (no_of_params * sizeof(param_t)) );
     //...
     //...

     objs++;  //Increment to point to the next item <-- Problem: ignores params[] size

     // blah
     // blah
     // blah
```

I have allocated memory to have 3 object_t with each object_t storing 5 param_t.

Memory allocation is fine and I could set values to the members.
objs[0] is perfectly fine.
Now if I increment the objs (objs++) to point to next object, it actually points to previous object's param address. It completely ignores the params[].
Now if I set values for the second *objs, it actually overwrites the params[] of previous *objs.

My question is: Is this a bug in C compiler?
If not, how do I traverse the objs?

Comment: Apart from the `sizeof` problems, it is quite likely that `&objs[0].params[objs[0].no_of_params]` will not meet the alignment requirements for the following `object_t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer of Bathsheba, you could better implement it as an array of pointers to the objects:

```
int no_of_objs = 3, no_of_params = 5;
object_t **objs = malloc(no_of_objs * sizeof(object_t *);
for (int i=0; i<no_of_objs; i++)
    objs[i]= malloc ((sizeof(object_t) + (no_of_params * sizeof(param_t)) );
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug in the C compiler, just a drawback of using variable length arrays.

Compilers are allowed to treat the variable length array member of the `struct` as not contributing to the `sizeof`.

This effectively breaks pointer arithmetic, and it means you can't easily "traverse the objects", as you put it.

That's life I'm afraid. A good enough reason for dropping variable length arrays as a compulsory requirement from C11.

Comment: I agree it is quite a task. I think one should avoid variable length arrays unless absolutely required.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to allocate this memory as a single block, you need to determine a suitably aligned element size:

```
size_t object_t_size(size_t nparams)
{
    return (offsetof(object_t, params[nparams]) | (_Alignof(object_t) - 1)) + 1;
}
```

Here, `nparams` is the number of `param_t` elements allocated for the `params` flexible array member of `object_t`.

For traversing forwards through a block of memory containing a collection of `object_t`s with `params` flexible array members, you need a way to find the position of the next `object_t`:

```
object_t *next_object_t(object_t *obj, size_t nparams)
{
    return (object_t *)((char *)obj + object_t_size(nparams));
}
```

The above can be used even if the `object_t`s have different sizes (including their `params` flexible array member) as long as the sizes of each individual `object_t` is known and does not change after allocation (or at least, not without code to reallocate the memory and shuffle around the contents to expand or reduce the size of a particular `object_t`).

If all the `object_t`s in the collection have the same size (including the fixed size of their `params` flexible array member), you can get a pointer to the *ith* element:

```
object_t *indexed_object_t(object_t *base, size_t nparams, size_t idx)
{
    return (object_t *)((char *)base + object_t_size(nparams) * idx);
}
```

Note that the above function is unsuitable for indexing backwards from an arbitrary element. That could be fixed by using a signed type for the index and casting the return value of `object_t_size` to a suitably wide signed integer type:

```
object_t *indexed_object_t(object_t *base, size_t nparams, int idx)
{
    return (object_t *)((char *)base + (intmax_t)object_t_size(nparams) * idx);
}
```

Comment: Typecast to char* and manual increment is a good technique. It does the trick. Thanks.
Now I'm on to variable length array in the param_t  (nested structures with both having variable length array) :)